# Unity fresh Scene is too dark

Tags: unity-game-engine

When creating a new scene with the HDR Template,
the scene is completely dark compared to the sample scene.

Sample Scene:
[image]

New Scene:
[image]

even when adding the example assets to the new scene the scene is too dark:

[image]

Game View and Scene View look almost the same in this case aswell.

Comment: Did you check the light settings are the same? default doesnt mean same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copying every single lighting setting from the sample scene into the new scene i still saw no changes.

So i tried a couple of things until i found the solution:

I needed to include the post processing volume into the new scene with following settings:
[image]

So i guess before dealing with any more hdr lighting stuff i should look into volumes, reflector probes and light probe groups.

Hope i could help you with that future unity game developer who stumbled upon the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Window>Rendering>Lighting Settings and at the bottom of the window click the "Generate Lighting" button. You can also set the checkbox to keep it updating automatically.

Comment: copying the settings from the sample scene did not fix the issue